# System.BadImageFormatException asp.net boilerplate

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I have been having issues with boilerplate i am just starting out with the use of it but every time i download the template it gives me this error not sure why it does this.

any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## .NET Core 2.1

This bug has been fixed in .NET Core 2.1: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23229

## .NET Core 2.0

Delete the `bin` folder in the Web project and rebuild the solution.

Add the following to your project file:

```html
<Target Name="RemoveNetFxForceConflicts" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'netfx.force.conflicts'" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: i did this did not work still throws the same error thank you for trying

Comment: hi sorry it didn't work but i have moved on from it  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As @aaron stated, the solution is deleting bin folder.

In details;

- If you are using IIS, restart IIS.
- Close Visual Studio. Delete all BIN & OBJECT folders.
- Update Visual Studio to the latest. 15.4.0
- Making sure ApplicationPoolIdentity's .NET CLR version is set to "No Managed Code".

*PS: This issue is not directly related to aspnetboilerplate. It's about corefx...*

Further information: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23229